# When I insert BuildingBlockEntries in Word2007 VBA, can I add other params than Where:= and Rich Text?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

In example:

```
For Each mytemplate In Templates
       If mytemplate.Name = "Normal.dotx" Then _
          mytemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Leeg").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256797.aspx), no.  It only accepts parameters *Where* and *RichText*.

Take a look at the [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258551.aspx), though, of a BuildingBlock Object.